# Sci-Fi Short Story Identifcation. Time Travel, Takes Place on Titan?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

I am looking to find a short story wherein a group of people leave their ship to respond to a distress signal on Titan (maybe?) They head into some kind of ice caverns on a mountain. The crew come to discover that they are the ones who sent the signal when they see their ship landing to rescue them.

I read this in a high school sci-fi class so it may have been published in a *Playboy* anthology, or in a textbook.

Comment: They used Playboy anthologies in your high school?

Comment: *"I read this in a high school sci-fi class so it may have been published in a Playboy anthology, or in a textbook."* Uhm ... a large fraction of the stories the *Playboy* runs have a non-trivial amount of 'adult' content. At least where I grew up that would pretty much exclude it being used in a high school course. Are you sure that's right?

Comment: @dmckee - I'm always surprised by how little adult content there is in the old Playboy anthologies and how tame the adult content is by modern standards.

Comment: @Valorum Hmmm ... I have to admit I am not familiar with their stories from before the mid-mumbles. Most of the stories I'm familiar with that ran in *Playboy* would not have been acceptable in my high school not withstanding that it was very liberal by the standards of that time and place. I would agree that the stories are usually pretty vanilla and un-threatening; it's just that the bar was pretty set pretty low.

Comment: The vast majority of the stories were tame. I think there was one story they had us read that regarded reproduction, but it wasn't anything terribly interesting in that regard. I think there was another text book we had, but I can't for the life of me remember what it even looked like, much less what it was called.

Comment: I also recall there was much giggling at the mention of Playboy, and that our teacher had to explain that they actually published a decent amount of general sci-fi.

Comment: You read it in high school? So that would have been what, the 1950s?

Comment: @user14111 I took the class in '07-'08 though the story would have likely been anywhere from the 50's onward. I sincerely doubt it would be more recent than the 80's, though.

Comment: [*The Playboy Book of Science Fiction*](https://www.amazon.com/Playboy-Science-Fiction-Alice-Turner/dp/0061073423)

Comment: I contacted some people who work at my high school to see if any of them actually knew what books we used for the class. Still waiting to hear back.

Comment: Ursula LeGuin's "Nine Lives" was first published in *Playboy* , November 1969 was first published in Playboy, September, 1975. The ISFDB lists more than 50 separate years in which at least one issue of Playboy contained at least one item of genre content. That is the actual magazine, Manay Playboy anthologies are also listed. For example  Best of Playboy Fiction, Vol 2 (1996) lists pieces by Tom Robbins,  Kurt Vonnegut, Jr., Roald Dahl, and T. Coraghessan Boyle. Many others could be named.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there's a good chance you're remembering ***[Time Wants a Skeleton](http://Time%20Wants%20a%20Skeleton)*** by Ross Rocklynne, first published in the [June 1941 edition](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?57535) of *Astounding Science-Fiction*.

It has most of what you describe and was published in at least one Playboy anthology.

The story can be read at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v27n04_1941-06_AK/page/n7/mode/2up).

Comment: What *Playboy* anthology was "Time Wants a Skeleton" reprinted in? Seems unlikely.

Comment: There's a German playboy anthology called Die besten Stories von 1941" from 1981 and I assumed there was an English edition of it. I didn't dig too far into it.

Comment: I see. The English language edition does not have "Playboy" in its title. http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?34138

Comment: This was exactly it, thank you so much! looking at the comments that book is the anthology I was thinking of.